# How do I set a cookie in a wordpress ajax request handler?

Tags: ajax, cookies, wordpress

I am trying to set a cookie in a wp ajax request handler without any success.
Hope someone can help me.
Here is client-side code:

```
var foo = $('#foo');
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type:   'post',
    dataType:   'json',
    cache:  'false',
    data: { 'action' : 'foo', 'foo' : foo.val(), 'nonce' : foo.data('nonce') },
    success: function(data) { console.debug(data) },
    error: function() { console.error('fail') }
});
```

Here is the plugin:

```
function foo() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'foo-my-nonce', 'nonce', 'what?!' );

    if (isset($_POST['foo'])) {
        $dir = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $dir['dirname'] = $dir['dirname'].'/';
        setcookie('foo', $_POST['foo'], time()+62208000, $dir['dirname'], $_SE    RVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        $output = array('response' => 'success', 'message' => 'have fun');
    }
    else
        $output = array('response' => 'failed', 'message' => 'you are a loser');

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode( $output );
    exit;
 }

 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo','foo');
```

Comment: What are you seeing that shows it's not working?

Comment: This is obviously an example! My real function is executed and anything goes fine except the setcookie(), I haven't debug this function because I don't know how to do that in an ajax manner

Comment: how do you know it's not working? What are you seeing? What's it doing?

Comment: So I update a custom field in the same function and that work. Also I perform a check on $_COOKIE['foo'] and it is not setted (in a non ajax function)

Comment: Thanks. This works great for me! I've made a customized version for my website with a few tweaks such as outputting different email addresses based on a cookie check and displaying a loading gif on request etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok guys I fixed that. 
In order to make it working you must set the cookie path to "/" (the root) of the website, instead of the current 'post' or 'dirname':

Instead of:

`setcookie('foo', $_POST['foo'], time()+62208000, $dir['dirname'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Use:

`setcookie('foo', $_POST['foo'], time()+62208000, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Comment: **Tip**: rather than using a hard-coded path and $_SERVER variable, it's preferred to use some WP constants: `COOKIEPATH` and `COOKIE_DOMAIN` - example:  `setcookie('foo', $_POST['foo'], time()+62208000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);`