# jQuery with AJAX to store cookie not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to store a cookie, containing user's zip code, when the user logs in. For the PHP login, it works fine, using "wp_login" action hook. But my site also has AJAX login. So far my code is not working, but it's also not throwing any error.

jQuery:

```
        function get_zipcode() {
            jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'user_zipcode_callback'}, 
            function (zipcode) {
                Cookies.remove('visitor_zipcode');

                if (zipcode != '') {
                    var CookieDate = new Date;
                    CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear() +10);
                    document.cookie = 'visitor_zipcode=' + zipcode + '; expires=' + CookieDate.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
                }
            }).then(function(){
                window.location.reload(true);
            });
        }
        jQuery(document).on('lrm_user_logged_in', function(response, $form) {
            get_zipcode();
        });
```

AJAX call to get user's zip code:

```
function user_zipcode_callback() {
    $user_zipcode = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"shipping_postcode",true);
    if($user_zipcode == '') $user_zipcode = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"billing_postcode",true);
    echo $user_zipcode;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
add_action('wp_ajax_user_zipcode_callback', 'user_zipcode_callback');
```

This is the one for PHP login, it's unrelated, but maybe can add a context:

```
function add_zipcode_cookie($user_login) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['visitor_zipcode'])) {
        unset($_COOKIE['visitor_zipcode']);
        setcookie('visitor_zipcode', '', time() - 3600, '/');
    }

    $user_obj = get_user_by('login', $user_login );
    $user_zipcode = get_user_meta($user_obj->ID,"shipping_postcode",true);
    if($user_zipcode == '') $user_zipcode = get_user_meta($user_obj->ID,"billing_postcode",true);
    if($user_zipcode != '') {
        setcookie('visitor_zipcode', $user_zipcode, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'add_zipcode_cookie');
```

Comment: Do you have control of the backend?  If so, setting the cookie on the response would make all this a mute question.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that in order to create a session, the PHP server needs to be informed that a session needs to be created. In other words, the backend should create a PHPSESSID cookie (whose value can be set by us, as is your requirement. )

As explained here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531421/6653215

please use setcookie function in the server side.

Hope this helps